# Voice Recording and play with PHP

Tags: php, voice-recording

I want to implement recording and play into site in PHP. I have already implement with https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs, but it not working in mobile browser.

Please suggest me any third-party API or code in PHP.

Comment: Please describe your problem in greater detail. For example, does it work in desktop browsers? What does your code look like? Is it a client-side or server-side problem? What are you using PHP for here? And so on...

Comment: @JensonMJohn, Question says `audio recording`

Comment: I am building one Website for tourguide, where need to user upload his  voice. So user can upload his voice and it should play on website. I have using backend as PHP. so i mention it.

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura Yes, but your question is very open-ended. The only thing we know is that you use Recorderjs and PHP... We are not here to do unpaid work for you, so please explain **what the problem is**. What *kind* of API are you looking for? What should the PHP code do? Should it organize audio files on the file system, or convert the audio to some other file format, etc.?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen User can record his audio from browser and save file to server then any visitor can play that audio and listen user voice. I have did code with Recorderjs, but it not working into mobile browser because Flash version. so i though if there is any cloud API which provide platform independent voice recording and playing.